# Cowpatty handshakes vs Pyrit

Tags: wpa2

At the moment I have a strange problem: I captured a pcap-file, and pyrit and aircrack tell me that it contains a valid handshake. But cowpatty complains about not having a full handshake, thus making it unable to crack the pcap file. Why? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue in the past. I think you experience the same problem ([it is described here](http://www.exploresecurity.com/william-wpawpa2-4-way-handshake-extraction-script/))
Please answer the following :

- What software did you use to capture the handshake ?
- If you open the handshake with Wireshark, how does it look like (screenshot) ?
- **$ pyrit -r "yourcapture*.pcap" analyze** give you what status (good/workable/bad)?
- Did you 'clean' the capture using 'wpaclean' or other tool ? (In my experience it can damage your pcap rather than 'cleaning it properly')

The only solution I have found at the time was to capture a new handshake / or clean it myself.

Comment: I used airodump for capturing the handshake, and pyrit tells me that it found a good handshake. Interestingly, the version of cowpatty which is installed in Kali can handle the file, but cowpatty from the website compiled by myself can not...